# Is there an intuitive reason as to why there is no phase transition to get to a degenerate Fermi gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

Cooling a bosonic gas leads to a **phase transition** into the [Bose-Einstein condesate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate). This is characterised by a symmetry broken ( U(1), by choosing a specific phase for the macroscopic wavefunction) and by discountinuous behavoiur of some thermodyamics quantities and their derivates - e.g. the heat capacities.

On the other hand, cooling a fermionic gas leads to a **crossover** into the a [Fermi degenerate gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas).

Is there an intuitive reason as to why the latter does not constitute a phase transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of phase transitions, interactions are the main source of intuition.  You can imagine a collective field which biases the order parameter.  For non-interacting bosons, the collective field is coming from the statistics instead of an interaction (an energy).  Thus, it’s hard to identify the collective field as a term in an action or free energy.  Instead we have to think more intuitively about these statistics and how a collective field forms and acts on its constituents.  First the statistics of indistinguishable particles can be understood as distinguishable particles communicating with each other by constructive and deconstructive interference.  For fermions the “signal” communicated is different from each particle as each particle is in a different state,  thus the collective interference pattern cast by the N-1 particles on the N particle is noisy and random. While for bosons the signal is the same from each particle and the interference pattern reinforces its self.  This reinforcement is the same sort of feedback process that interactions produce when forming a collective field in a classical phase transition.

For interacting systems,  the collective inter-particle interference is not the only way particles communicate. In bosinic systems the suppression of thermal excitations is further reinforced by interactions and produces a gap in the excitation spectrum.

While interactions produce no collective field in interacting fermions for completely repulsive interactions.  For attractive interactions,  fermions pair into bosons and then condense.

Comment: For bosonic condensate, the role of the (repulsive) interaction is to stabilize the condensate against fragmentation. Interaction by itself does not "reinforce" collective interference. You can create two non-interacting BEC side-by-side, release them, and observe fringes as they expand. I put (repulsive) as a qualifier because BEC will collapse with attractive interaction. The core of the normal to BEC transition is the saturation of the excited states by thermal atoms, not interactions. Maybe interaction can modify the density of states and affect critical temperature, but that's it.

Comment: My language was poor,  when I said interactions reinforce, I mean interaction strengthen the effect of the collective field on non condensed atoms.  That is they "reinforce" the force preventing thermal atoms from being excited. by creating a energetic gap.  This is how it increases the critical temperature.

Comment: The interference you mention is between the two condensed mode of the BECs. I'm describing the way multiple particles see "interact" with each other via the boson and fermi statistics even when they don't have interactions. This is an interference between the wave function of 1 particle and that of all the other particles. It would be very hard to create experiment to see clean interference fringes of this type.

Comment: Bose-Einstein condensation is a statistical phase transition, which can occur even in the complete absence of any interaction. An ideal Bose gas *does* undergo a BEC transition.

Comment: DSuchet, my first comment is about the case with interactions. the full response describes how you can get an intuition on the statistical transition via analogy to a system with interactions. No one has claimed you need interactions for the BEC transition.